# Ingesting data from eventhub to multiple datalake store folders

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-eventhub

We are planning to use EventHub capture for ingesting data from EventHub to data lake store. We have messages come in to EventHub from multiple sources and would like to route them to different folders on the Datalake based on the EventHub message header. What are the various options to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect Azure Event Hubs with Data Lake Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522725/connect-azure-event-hubs-with-data-lake-store)

Answer (score -1):

One option is Azure Data Factory https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/